# Salesforce Apex Test Failures - Can someone explain the Error Message?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I try to deploy an updated Apex Class.
But I alway get this error:

```
OCRServiceHandlerTest   testProcessOCRTickets   System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Stack Trace: Class.OCRServiceHandler.getAttributesInfo: line 204, column 1 Class.OCRServiceHandler.parseResponse: line 179, column 1 Class.OCRServiceHandler.processFileData: line 142, column 1 Class.OCRServiceHandler.processOCRTickets: line 66, column 1
```

and also this one:

```
OCRServiceHandlerTest   testProcessOcrTicketCtrl    System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Stack Trace: Class.OCRServiceHandler.getAttributesInfo: line 204, column 1 Class.OCRServiceHandler.parseResponse: line 179, column 1 Class.OCRServiceHandler.processFileData: line 142, column 1 Class.OCRServiceHandler.processOCRTickets: line 66, column 1
```

I have to admit, that this is my first time developing something in APEX.

Line 204 looks like this:

```
String authorityEmail = getCompleteJoinedContent(page?.prediction?.authority_email.values);
```

In the API and Object this field is an EMail-Type-Field.
Do I need to change Line 204 to EMail or something like that?

Can somebody help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing, `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`, is a common one in Apex (and other object-oriented languages). It means that you're trying to access a property or method on an object that hasn't been initialized (i.e., it's `null`).

From the stack trace you provided, it seems that the error originates from the `getAttributesInfo` method at line 204. The line in question is:

```
String authorityEmail = getCompleteJoinedContent(page?.prediction?.authority_email.values);
```

The use of the safe navigation operator (`?.`) in Apex is to prevent null dereference exceptions. However, the error suggests that something in this chain is null and you're trying to access a property or method on it.

Here's a breakdown of what could be null:

1. `page`
2. `page.prediction`
3. `page.prediction.authority_email`

If any of these are null, then trying to access the `values` property on `authority_email` will throw the exception you're seeing.

To troubleshoot and fix the issue:

1. **Check Object Initialization**: Ensure that the `page` object and its nested properties (`prediction` and `authority_email`) are properly initialized before this line of code is executed.
2. **Null Checks**: Add null checks before accessing nested properties. For example:

```
String authorityEmail;
if(page != null && page.prediction != null && page.prediction.authority_email != null) {
    authorityEmail = getCompleteJoinedContent(page.prediction.authority_email.values);
}
```

3. **Field Type**: The error doesn't seem to be related to the field type (`EMail-Type-Field`). The issue is with the object being null. However, once you resolve the null issue, ensure that the `getCompleteJoinedContent` method can handle the data type you're passing to it.
4. **Test Data**: If this error is occurring during a test class execution, ensure that your test data setup is correctly initializing the `page` object and its nested properties.
5. **Method Behavior**: Check the behavior of the `getCompleteJoinedContent` method. If this method doesn't handle null values gracefully, it could also be a source of the error.

Lastly, since you mentioned this is your first time developing in Apex, I'd recommend going through Salesforce's Apex Developer Guide, especially the sections on error handling and testing. It provides a comprehensive overview of the language and best practices.